# Efeito de transição de conteúdo em site

Tags: jquery, css, plugin

Visitei esse [site](http://blog.squarespace.com/blog/squarespace-student-discount) e gostei da forma que o conteúdo de move, quando é clicado em **More Articles** ou **Hide List**, gostarei de implementar em um site que estou desenvolvendo. Estou tendo dificuldades para encontrar o plugin que faz isso, inspecionei a página e vi que já um `mixpanel.2.js` só que não encontro a documentação para isso.
Alguém já utilizou isso? Há outra forma de fazer isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer utilizando a biblioteca [greensock](http://www.greensock.com/). Muito boa para animação em js.

Ela é usada dessa maneira:

**HTML**

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="cont1">
    <a href="#" id="back">BACK</a>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veritatis voluptate molestiae velit eius ullam recusandae aspernatur quae perspiciatis beatae facilis consequuntur soluta! Ipsam omnis impedit porro numquam neque aperiam atque.</p></div>


  <div class="cont2">
    <a href="#" id="more">MORE</a>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam animi officia consequatur quidem consequuntur? Hic similique veritatis porro. Cum quibusdam recusandae fuga beatae saepe deleniti iure sequi eveniet numquam veniam.</p></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
.cont1{
  background-color: #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 300px;
}

.cont2{
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 30px;
}
```

**Javascript com Greensock**

```
$("#more").click(function(){
  TweenMax.to($(".cont2"), 1, {left: 300});
});
$("#back").click(function(){
  TweenMax.to($(".cont2"), 1, {left: 0});
});
```

Fiz esse pequeno exemplo para você ver o funcionamento. Pode ver o exemplo [aqui](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/tgHmf).

Comment: Vou explicar um pouco melhor do que tenho hoje em dia.
Tenho uma div chamada `menu`, quando eu clico nela, uma outra div chamada `menufixo` que está como `display:none` fica `display:block`. Aí blz, pelo que vi terei que mudar minha extrutura, né?
Meu código http://jsfiddle.net/felipestoker/mHv7K/

Comment: Então Felipe, de acordo com o que você mandou acho q não vai mudar muita coisa não... Nesse caso que você mandou agora eu mudei só o posicionamento do right do seu css, e adicionei a biblioteca do greensock para trabalhar com o efeito. Fiz uma pequena transição saindo da direita para a esquerda. Caso seja um pouco diferente o que você for fazer a estrutura nem vai mudar mt não, o que muda será mais no css, mesmo assim seria pouca coisa.

veja como ficou: http://jsfiddle.net/mHv7K/3/

Comment: Consegui fazer do jeito que eu queria, excelente plugin. :D
Só uma dúvida, estou usando ele para quando eu clicar em `menu` ele joga toda uma div que tenho à direita para `right:300px`, só que alguns elementos estão sumindo, seria melhor trabalhar com o largura da tela ao invés disso, sabe como faço para capturar o tamanho da tela para que elementos não sumam?

Comment: pegar tamanho da tela em javascript é window.innerWidth;
e 
window.innerHeight;

Comment: Estou usando assim: http://jsfiddle.net/felipestoker/eY9b3/ o que acontece, que ao invés de eu usar `right:300px` acho que o ideal seria mexer na largura total da tela, para não esconder nenhum item, o processo então seria?
`    TweenMax.to($(".fundo1"), 0.5, {'window.innerWidth'-300px: "300px"});
` ou algo do gênero?

Comment: Eu não entendi muito bem o que você quer fazer quando diz "mexer na largura total da tela"... você quer colocar a div com a largura da tela atual?
se for isso a sua div tem q ter no css width: 100%
é isso?

Comment: O que acontece, é que a div `fundo1` por padrão tem 100%, quando eu clico no item `menu`, abre um menu fixo à direta que empura a div `fundo1` para a esquerda, quando ele empurra, ele tá escondendo alguns itens, então eu quero que a div `fundo1` apenas mude de largura, para não esconder nada, por isso queria calcular a largura total, só não sei como.

Comment: ahhh acho que entendi. Então seu js vai ter que ficar mais ou menos assim: http://jsfiddle.net/eY9b3/1/

Comment: Eu consegui da seguinte forma: `TweenMax.to($(".fundo1"), 0.5, {width: ($(window).width() -320)});`

:P

Comment: sim, acaba dando no mesmo, `window.innerWidth` é a mesma coisa que `$(window).width()`, mas sem usar jQuery... no caso de vc ter colocado direto o `-320` lembre-se de mudar por ai também caso vc mude o tamanho dele no css em algum momento... no caso do `$("#menuFixo").width()` ele ja pega o tamanho que está definido no css

mas que bom que conseguiu

Comment: Consegui sim, a sua ajuda com o plugin foi essencial. Abraço! :D